# Pytorch based Bert NER for transfer learning/retraining

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, transfer-learning

I trained an Bert-based NER model using Pytorch framework by referring the below article.

https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert/.

After training the model using this approach, I saved that model using torch.save() method. Now, I want to retrain the model with new dataset.

Can someone please help me on how to perform retraining/transfer learning as I'm new to NLP and transformers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can read the doc on pytorch loading, the model that can be very helpful to retrain the save model in a new dataset. I will provide the example of loading a save model. That can be very helpful to you

Original Doc :- https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Example code :- https://pythonguides.com/pytorch-load-model/

This two link are very helpful to train the new dataset on save model